# How to get Python 2.7 to PATH?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

so I'm trying to download Python 2.7, And when I do there's no checkmark to add it to PATH. I haven't seen this problem anywhere else, so I was wondering if it was a problem with my computer.

Comment: First --> please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A are very unclear topic! Improve your post and give enougth info as we can help you to solve your issue (what's your os, purpose ... etc) !

Comment: Maybe the installer adds the Python executable to your path without asking your permission via check box. Have you completed the installation process? Have you confirmed that the Python directory isn't in your path? What if you reboot first?

Comment: What's your OS ?